# How to get Contents from HTML string in Array

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I am working with some html contents. The format of the HTML is like below.

```
<li>
  <ul>
     <li>Test1</li>
     <li>Test2</li>
  </ul>
  Odd string 1
  <ul>
     <li>Test3</li>
     <li>Test4</li>
  </ul>
  Odd string 2
  <ul>
     <li>Test5</li>
     <li>Test6</li>
  </ul>
<li>
```

There can be multiple "odd string" in html content. So I want all the "odd string" in array. Is there any easy way ? (I am using C# and HtmlAgilityPack)

Comment: will they always be between </ul> and <ul>?

Comment: @Jonesy Yes they will be always between </ul> and <ul>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `ul` elements and refer to next sibling node, which will be your text:

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.Load(html_file);
var odds = from ul in html.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul")
           let sibling = ul.NextSibling
           where sibling != null && 
                 sibling.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text && // check if text node
                 !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sibling.InnerHtml)
           select sibling.InnerHtml.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(HTMLString, "</ul>.*?<ul>", RegexOptions.SingleLine);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    String oddstring = match.ToString().Replace("</ul>","").Replace("<ul>","");
}
```

Comment: OP probably needs a solution using HtmlAgilityPack (notice tags and the last sentence of the question)

Answer (score 0):

Get all the `ul` descendants and check it the next sibling node is `HtmlNodeType.Text` and if is not empty:

```
List<string>oddStrings = new List<string>();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (HtmlNode ul in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul"))
{
    HtmlNode nextSibling = ul.NextSibling;
    if (nextSibling != null && nextSibling.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        string trimmedText = nextSibling.InnerText.Trim();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedText))
        {
            oddStrings.Add(trimmedText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agility Pack can already query those texts

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html[1]/body[1]/li[1]/text()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPATH:

```
//body/li[1]/text()
```